# Methods without GOT slots

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

When I am compiling my program the build output says

"Methods without GOT slots: 0 (0%)"

I am using Xamarin and writing a program for the iPad.  There are no errors in the build and the program runs just fine.  I assume because there are 0 methods without GOT slots it would work right?

What is a GOT slot and how do methods have or don't have them?  What are things to look out for when coding so that I don't run into problems with this if it is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are **Global Offset Table**.

To keep it a short story, do **not** worry about the output of the AOT compiler if it does not return an error.

If you're curious about the AOT process [it](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aRuntime%3aDocumentation%3aAOT) from the Mono wiki. It's not 100% identical to what Xamarin.iOS is using (full AOT) but it's an interesting read to satisfy most curiosity.